# Scrapy - use multiple IP Addresses for a host

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Wasn't able to find anything in the docs/SO relating to my question.
So basically I'm crawling a website with 8 or so subdomains
They are all using Akamai/CDN.
My question is if I can find Ips of a few different Akamai data centres can, I somehow explicitly say this subdomain should use this ip for the host name etc.. So basically override the auto dns resolving...
As this would allow greater efficiency and I would imagine less likely to be throttled as I'd be distributing the crawling.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set your DNS names manually in your `hosts` file. On windows this can be found at `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` and on Linux in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Yea I thought that may be an options. Thanks! For my current spider this should be perfect. But I wonder out of interest if its possible for the same domain i.e no subdomains,to alternate ip addresses while scrapy runs?